# titlesec VS amsart

Tags: packages, document-classes, documentation

I am just wondering why the `titlesec` package doesn't work well with the `amsart` document class. For example, in the code below the first `\section` seems to work fine whereas the second doesn't even compile in the first place. In fact, I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct 

l.5 \section{more lalala}

?
```

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section*{lalala}
\section{more lalala}
\end{document}
```

I'm not looking for a solution to the problem (cause I'm not gonna be using `titlesec`), but I want to know why this (and possibly numerous other similar errors) happens.

Comment: It didn't surprise me at all that `titlesec` doesn't work with `amsart`. After all `amsart` redefines some of the code for section headings quite heavily, which means that it may also define commands upon which `titlesec` relies in a way incompatible with the `titlesec` approach. But the `titlesec` documentation says "Titlesec works with the standard classes and with many others, including the AMS ones, and it runs smoothly with `hyperref` (However, be aware the AMS classes reimplement the original internal commands. These changes will be lost here.).", so maybe it *should* work?

Comment: Note that you only showed a fragment of the error so did not show which command is undefined (`\@secnumpunct`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you. That is indeed the full error I get. And I don't understand why.

Comment: section headings are defined by the class not by the latex format. titlesec patches the standard classes and may work with other classes if they use similar code but if it doesn't work with a class that is no real surprise.